# How to pass generic protocol as function parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I have to pass a protocol as a parameter to a function. Protocol is generic, has associated type. I couldn't find a good way to do that.

What I want to achieve basically storing a key-value pair in json.
So I have one Generic Datatype protocol which sets/gets value (sets and gets according to datatype)

In another protocol I want to pass this generic Datatype protocol as a function parameter.

```
protocol Datatype {
    associatedtype dataType
    
    func get(json: JSON) -> dataType?
    func set(json:inout JSON, key: String, value: dataType)
}

class DatatypeString: Datatype{
    
    typealias dataType = String

    func get(json: JSON) -> dataType? {
       return json.stringValue
    }

    func set(json: inout JSON, key: String, value: dataType) {
        json[key] = JSON(value)
    }
}

class DatatypeInt: Datatype{
    typealias dataType = Int
    
    func get(json: JSON) -> Int? {
        return json.intValue
    }
    
    func set(json: inout JSON, key: String, value: Int) {
        json[key] = JSON(value)
    }
}
```

In the below code I'm getting **Protocol 'Datatype' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements**

```
protocol Final {
    func set<T>(key: String, type: Datatype ,value: T) //getting error
}
```

```
class A : Final {
    var root:JSON = [:]
    
    func set<T>(key: String, type: Datatype, value: T) {
        type.set(json: &root, key: key, value: value)
    }
```

```
class test {
   let a = A()
   let dataType = DatatypeString()
   a.set("key",datatype, "VALUE")
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you want to implement `set`?

Comment: Swift protocols are _not_ generic. What you mean is a protocol with associated types. This is not the same, and there _may_ be generic protocols in the future.

Comment: @Sweeper added implementation of set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `Datatype` as a generic constraint:

```
func set<T: Datatype>(key: String, type: T ,value: T.dataType)
```

Note how you also need to change the type of the `value` parameter to `T.dataType`, for this to be type safe. That is, the value you pass in must be the same type as the `dataType` of the `type` parameter.